# How many total colors in the urn, given that I've seen C colors in M draws?

Tags: probability, polya-urn-model

In this problem I want to estimate the unknown total number of colors of balls in the urn.  Say that there are N total balls in the urn, and after m draws (with replacement, if that makes it easier), I've observed k colors.  We can assume that all colors are equally represented.  N can be >> m, N >> k, which may also simplify.
Extreme cases:  If I've drawn 5 times and see blue,blue,blue,blue,blue, then it's likely that all the balls are blue and there are no other colors.  But if I draw 5 times and see red,orange,yellow,green,blue, then I have no idea how many colors there could be -- up to N.
My conjecture is that the answer is mk/(m - k) for N >> m but I'd appreciate a proper derivation.

Comment: You can find a probability to have $q$ colors for every $q>k$.

Comment: Yes, I know.  That would look something like 1 - sum( 1/q^m ) where the sum is over q = k+1 to infinity and m = number of samples taken.  But I want an estimator of the total number of colors, and also if possible an estimated variance for that result.

Comment: Since this is a real world problem (not homework!), I've turned to simulation to look for a solution.  It looks like k = K(1 - exp(-m/K)) [ where m = #draws, K = unknown total #colors, k = #different colors observed ] is an excellent fit (drawing with replacement), far better than my first conjecture above.

Comment: Did you manage to find an analytical solution?

Comment: No.   The simulation provided a sufficient answer for my business need but I would still like to see a good statistician find an analytical solution.

Comment: Hi Rob – not sure whether you're still around and whether you get notified if I close this as a duplicate, so here's a ping – enjoy the solution :-)